# Renamed title (display name) column randomly reverts back to title - SP2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, column

Something weird has happened this week on our SharePoint server. In various sites and sub-sites renamed "title" columns have randomly reverted back to the display name "Title". I realize that when you change a column name that previously existed that you're only changing the display name and not the static name, however, on numerous lists "Title" columns that were renamed to something else changed right back to "Title".

Has anyone else seen this behavior before or have any idea what would/could cause this? Thanks.

Comment: Is it dev environment or Production?? Some feature activation/deactivation done?

Comment: did you update the SharePoint environment by any chance ?

Comment: This is a production environment. No recently added/removed features lately to my knowledge. That doesn't mean it didn't happen though.

Comment: Do you have language packs installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we update the Title field in Site Level with the settings as
"Update all list columns based on this site column?" = Yes

cause this kind of behavior. Please check on the field is updated like this.

Comment: Are you referring to the site columns link in Site setting dashboard? I can't find the Title field at all under site columns.

Comment: Is there a way to see historically what a title field was renamed from? Someone did indeed make a change to the Content Type.